# view detail of single row of MySQL table in new page after click

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that display all job from MySQL database.

this is the code:

```
<?php


$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");


echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='table-fill'> 
<tr>
<th width='250px' position='fixed'>Job Title</th> 
<th width='150px'>Company Name</th>
<th width='100px'>Location</th>
<th>Closing Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['positiontitle'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['closingdate'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I want when i click on one of the job from the table then it should display the whole information in new page.

thanks

Comment: Add one more row with `Edit` link passing job id to other page. On that page find the job with id passed and display data as you want.

Comment: use **anchors** and, perhaps, **$_POST** or **$_GET**.. that's just an idea. Have you tried something else until now?

Comment: @briosheje yes i tried lots of way but no success.

Comment: @Rikesh, how to do that, i am new in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more row to your table

```
<th>View Job</th>
```

Your code :

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");


echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='table-fill'> 
<tr>
<th width='250px' position='fixed'>Job Title</th> 
<th width='150px'>Company Name</th>
<th width='100px'>Location</th>
<th>Closing Date</th>
<th>View Job</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['positiontitle'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['closingdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='job_details.php?id=".$row['job_id']."'>View Job</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
```

And in job_details.php fetch the details against the id and display the result on that page.

jobdetails.php :

```
<?php

   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE job_id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

   $jobdetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

   echo 'Position : '.$jobdetails['positiontitle'].'<br>';
   echo 'Company Name: '.$jobdetails['companyname'].'<br>';
   echo 'Location: '.$jobdetails['location'].'<br>';
   echo 'Closing Date: '.$jobdetails['closingdate'].'<br>';


?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i am new in php, can you please guide me how to fetch the detail against the id display the result on that page.

Comment: Thanks, but it says
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in E:\Easyphp\www\job\job.details.php on line 3.

Comment: @user3485423 can you tell me the table structure of job table?

Comment: Thanks Rakesh bro, it was my mistake. now it is ok. thanks again for your help.

Comment: any suggestion about this
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423463/mysql-delete-expired-jobs-from-database?noredirect=1#comment36079156_23423463)

Comment: can you please help me in this regards. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602784/hit-counter-using-job-id

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this id= instead of id=".$row['job_id']."