# Hit counter using job id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show that how many times a job have been viewed by visitors using their id which have been called from MySQL database.

Below is the code in page job.details.php.

```
<div style="width:900px;">
    <div style="float:left; width:200px;"class="ara-form"><header style="font-size:12px; color:#666666; font:Arial, sans-serif; padding:7px;"><?php

   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE jobid = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

   $jobdetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo '<strong>Job Title</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['positiontitle'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Company Name</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['companyname'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Location</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['location'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Closing Date</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['closingdate'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Number of Vacancy</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['numberofvacancy'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Job Category</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['jobcategory'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Duration</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['duration'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Employment Type</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['employmenttype'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Salary</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['salary'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Timing</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['timing'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Nationality</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['nationality'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Experience</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['experience'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Education</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['education'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'<hr class="job">';


?></header></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:600px;" class="ara-form">
    <fieldset style="font-size:12px; color:#666666; font:Arial, sans-serif;">
    <?php

    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Company Background</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['background'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Job Summary</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['summary'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Job Duties and Responsibilities</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['duty'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Qualification</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['qualification'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Skills</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['skill'].'<hr class="job"></p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Submission Guideline</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['submission'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Words to search this job</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['search'].'</p></br>';
    ?>
    </fieldset></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.4%; background:#ccc;">three</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is an example of the jobs that i have been called by their id from MySQL:
http://example.com/job/job.details.php?id=171

Comment: That data is not temporary storage, so you will have to save it into the database. Make a column maybe `hit_counter` and on this page, update it by one where `jobid` is `$_GET['id']`. You also should filter it by IP Address, else a refresh would increment the counter (even though the same user).

Comment: Beware with SQL injection, don't use params directly from `$_GET` or `$_POST` without sanitize it.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem? What are you struggleing with? If you lack a general understanding how to work with PHP/MySQL, you might be better off reading a tutorial or watching one on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @I can Has Kittenz, its not a temporary storage and needs persistence.
I can suggest creating a table something like :

```
mysql> create table `pageviews`(
->  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
->  `job_id` int,
-> `remote_host` varchar(45)
-> );
```

PHP Part:

```
$ipaddress  =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$job_id     =   $_GET['id'];
/*
 * Checking if an entry exists for this JOB ID with this REMOTE HOST
 */
$query  =   "SELECT id FROM pageviews WHERE ".
                      "job_id=".$job_id." AND remote_host='".$ipaddress."'";
$result =   mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 1){
/*
 * There is no entry for this job_id.
 * So create an entry
 */
    $query = "INSERT INTO pageviews (job_id,remote_host) VALUES ".
        "(".$job_id.",'".$ipaddress."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if($result){}
    else{
    echo 'There was a problem inserting the data';
    exit();
    }
}
```

If the above PHP part is inserted in your job.details.php, it will look at the client's IP address, the JOB ID which he/she is accessing and then insert an entry into your table IF he/she is accessing the JOB ID from an IP which does not exist in your table entries.

Now, you can get the 'Number of times jobid: $_GET['id'] was viewed' using a simple query :

```
$query  = "select id from pageviews where job_id=".$job_id."";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
echo "Number of times jobID: ".$job_id." was viewed = ".mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

NOTE: Client IP can be behind a proxy server, or the IP can be an internal IP from the LAN behind the proxy. So cannot really trust the value offered by $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

You are free to optimize any queries,sanitize inputs, create table in different ways. This is just one of the simple ways to achieve what you are basically looking for.

Comment: thanks @learner, i want to create the above database inside the database that i already have by the name of job.

Comment: You mean above 'table' inside your existing database?

Comment: thanks @learner, i want to create the above database inside the database that i already have by the name of job.
This is my database structure:
[link](http://s2.postimg.org/67hzzqvqh/Capture.jpg)

Comment: yes 
this is my table structure:

Comment: [link](http://s2.postimg.org/67hzzqvqh/Capture.jpg)

Comment: Job ID's might be unique in the table structure you have shown. So create a new TABLE (not database) as shown in my answer in the same database where you have your existing table. For more information on how to do that in phpmyadmin refer [this](http://www.fatcow.com/support/tutorials/view_tutorial.bml?kbid=5923)

Comment: when i do that i get this error in page loading: Notice: Undefined variable: dbc in E:\Easyphp\www\job\job.details.php on line 28

Comment: $dbc is the connection to your database in PHP file.
Here is the line of code that connects:
$dbc = mysqli_connect(<hostname>, <username>, <DB_password>,<DB_Name>) or die('Could not connect');

Comment: thanks @learner, but when i view a page a new row is creating in mysql

Comment: When you visit example.com/job/job.details.php?id=171 assuming your IP is 127.0.0.1, a new row will be created with job_id as 171 and remote_host as 127.0.0.1. Now when you refresh,the query that will be run is: SELECT id FROM pageviews WHERE job_id = 171 AND remote_host = '127.0.0.1'. Since a row already exists for that job ID and remote_host, mysqli_num_rows($result) will return 1 and hence a new row will not be created.

Comment: will it increase my database size. The next problem is this that empty rows will be also shown in my job list in the homepage.

Comment: Yes. I will not be able to assist on empty rows as there is no information on homepage, its queries and its empty rows.